# Xamarin - Update creating blank apps

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I've recently updated xamarin in visual studio but since then when I test my app on the emulator or on my phone it just appears blank with no buttons or text even though they are present in the axml view.

Thanks

Fraser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to this tutorial from James Montemagno about updating Xamarin to cycle 8:
http://motzcod.es/post/150380059392/preparing-machines-for-xamarin-cycle

Comment: I've given it a try but my apps still appear blank in the emulator. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Tried repeating those steps above again and that solved it.